# Merge [site-stats] into [statistics]

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

As the [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) tag already handles

> Questions about sizes and other quantities of Stack Exchange sites, e.g. number of questions, GB/day transferred, etc.

in other words: site statistics, I propose to merge/synonimize the smaller tag [site-stats](/questions/tagged/site-stats), having no excerpt/wiki, into the [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) tag.

Comment: Note – [site-stats] now has a tag excerpt and wiki. The excerpt reads: "for questions about the core statistics for sites that determine the health of a site relevant in the Area 51 phase of a site or during its lifetime to guide the site towards graduation." The tag wiki reads: "Site statistics are important when it comes to site graduation. Use this tag on questions to learn how these statistics are calculated, how you can influence them, what values you're looking for to go from beta to graduated. Occasional used to compare / compete between sites."

Comment: That said, the tag wikis seem to indicate that they have a lot of overlap, but they're not exactly the same – the [statistics] tag seems to be on a lot of questions that aren't about site statistics (especially with relation to the Area 51 process), despite what the tag wiki says. This may be because of the more generic name that doesn't mention site statistics specificaly...